# Area of shaded region circle help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find the area of the shaded region

[image]

Area of the sector is $240^\circ$ or $\frac{4\pi}{3}$

Next find $\frac{b\cdot h}{2}$ which is $\frac{2\cdot2}{2}$ which is $2$.

Then subtract the former from the latter: $\frac{4\pi}{3} - 2$

Therefore the answer is $~2.189$?

Is this correct?

Comment: The problem is that you've drawn the triangle as if it is a right triangle, when it isn't a right triangle. The answer(s) below show you the correct way of calculating the area of the triangle.

Comment: $h$ can be difficult to find in this instance. When you know the two sides of a triangle, there is a formula $Area=(1/2)ab\sin(C)$, where C is the angle between the two sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the  area that  corresponds to 120 degrees  or $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is one third of the total area of the circle $4\pi$ the area of the triangle is $\frac{bh}{2}$ but $h$ is not $2$ you need to project it,  since $\cos (\, 30 \text{ degrees}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ degrees to find $h = \sqrt{3}$ Therefore

$$\text{area} = \frac{4\pi}{3} - \sqrt{3}  = 2.4567 \cdots  $$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, aperture angle $\theta=120^\circ=\frac{2\pi}{3}$

Area of shaded portion  $$=\text{(area of the sector)}-\text{(area of isosceles triangle)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(\theta)(r^2)-\frac{1}{2}(r^2)\sin\theta$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2\pi}{3}(2)^2-\frac{1}{2}(2)^2\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}$$
$$=2.456739397$$

**Edit**:

> **Note:** Area of an isosceles triangle having each of the equal sides $a$ & an angle $\theta$ included between them then the area of the triangle $$=\frac{1}{2}(a)(a)\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}a^2\sin\theta$$